# How to auto check page and make tags invisible in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is my jsp file containing two useful parameter from backend, pageIndex and numOfPages. I would like to do a simple validation where javascript can check and make next or previous invisible. However,it seems the function is not even activated. I wonder whether there is any way to call the validation function every time the page is loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>NTU Student Course Planner</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
    hr {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-style: inset;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
</style>
<body class="w3-light-grey w3-content" style="max-width:1600px" onload="copy();">

<!-- Sidebar -->
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-white w3-animate-left" style="z-index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidebar"><br>
    <div class="w3-container">
        <a href="#" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-hide-large w3-right w3-jumbo w3-padding w3-hover-grey" title="close menu">
            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        </a>
        <img src="assets/calendar.png" style="width:40%;" class="w3-round"><br><br>
        <h4><b>Z440's Timetable Generator</b></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-bar-block">
        <a href="index.jsp" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding w3-text-teal"><i class="fa fa-th-large fa-fw w3-margin-right"></i>Create Timetable</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens -->
<div class="w3-overlay w3-hide-large w3-animate-opacity" onclick="w3_close()" style="cursor:pointer" title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="portfolio">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/calendar.png" style="width:65px;" class="w3-circle w3-right w3-margin w3-hide-large w3-hover-opacity"></a>
        <span class="w3-button w3-hide-large w3-xxlarge w3-hover-text-grey" onclick="w3_open()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
        <div class="w3-container">>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-section w3-bottombar w3-padding-16">
                <h1><b>NTU Student Course Planner</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <div class="container-1">
                <br>
                <h5><b>Courses Selected:</b></h5>
                        <p id = "courselist"></p>
                <h5><b>Module Code Selected:</b></h5>
                        <p id = "moduleCodeList">${timetables.get(pageIndex).courseIndexList}</p>
                        <hr>
                        <br>
                        <h6><center>Generated Timetable</center></h6>
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <a href="#" onclick="decrement()">< Previous</a>
                                <a href="#" style="padding: 10px 16px">Download</a>
                                <a href="#" style="padding: 10px 30px" onclick="increment()">Next ></a>
                            </div>
                            <form id="searchForm1" name="searchForm1" action="nextTimetable"  method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="pageIndex" id="pageIndex"  value="${pageIndex + 1}">
                                <input type="text" name="num" id="num"  value="${numOfPages}">
                                <input type="submit" id = "Next" value="Next">
                            </form>
                            <form id="searchForm2" name="searchForm2" action="previousTimetable"  method="post">
                                <input type="submit" id = "Previous" value="Previous">
                            </form>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                <div id="tableDiv">
                        <table id="timeTableTable">
                            <tr>
                        <th>TIME</th>
                        <th>MON</th>
                        <th>TUE</th>
                        <th>WED</th>
                        <th>THU</th>
                        <th>FRI</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>0830-0930</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][0]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][0]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][0]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][0]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>0930-1030</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][1]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][1]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][1]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][1]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][1]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1030-1130</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][2]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][2]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][2]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][2]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][2]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1130-1230</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][3]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][3]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][3]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][3]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][3]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1230-1330</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][4]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][4]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][4]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][4]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][4]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1330-1430</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][5]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][5]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][5]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][5]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][5]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1430-1530</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][6]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][6]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][6]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][6]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][6]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1530-1630</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][7]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][7]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][7]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][7]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][7]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1630-1730</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][8]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][8]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][8]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][8]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][8]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1730-1830</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][9]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][9]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][9]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][9]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][9]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1830-1930</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][10]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][10]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][10]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][10]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][10]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1930-2030</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][11]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][11]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][11]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][11]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][11]}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2030-2130</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[0][12]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[1][12]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[2][12]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[3][12]}</td>
                        <td>${timetables.get(pageIndex).message[4][12]}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- End of Page Content -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript file

```
function validateNextPrevious() {
    if(document.getElementById("pageIndex").value == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("Previous").style.display = "none";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("pageIndex").value == document.getElementById("num").value)
    {
        document.getElementById("Next").style.display = "none";
    }
}
window.onload = function () {

    validateNextPrevious();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to make the page received static resources like js file, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js" />` isn't the right way, try:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/scripts.js"/ >
```